# rPad ou PadRight na exportação de texto do FastReport VCL

Tags: delphi, fast-reports

Estou desenvolvendo um layout que servirá como base para exportar um arquivo de texto padrão CNAB 240 ou CNAB 400 (*boletos*).
Consegui gerar as informações, tudo certinho.

O problema está que as linhas precisam conter exatamente 240 caracteres (ou 400).
Inseri um `memo` no final de cada linha com espaços vazios para completar o número de caracteres necessários e tentei combinar as propriedades do report, da banda e mesmo do `memo`, mas nenhuma deu certo.
Seria necessário algo como *rPad* ou *PadRight* (ao menos que gerasse esse efeito).

Há como resolver isso?

Aspectos técnicos:

- Versão do Fastreport: 6.7.9;
- Tipo do relatório: DotMatrixReport

  (DMP);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei qual versão do Delphi está usando, mas se for uma versão mais recente, na class helper`TStringHelper` tem a função `PadRight()`

Só precisa incluir no uses `System.StrUtils`

exemplo de utilização:

`strVar.PadRight(240, ' ')`